# For R, how do I determine the origin when there is an error in running POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

There is an error thrown saying that I did not specify an origin - I thought the origin was automatically 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and that I do not need to specify. Code worked before when coworker wrote it. How do I correct this error? Below is the partial code (I can post the full script too if that's helpful)

Sample Data csv:

> YEARMONTH,COUNT,ZONE,DOMAIN
>
> 2011-04-01 00:00:00,1786,City1,Domain1
>
> 2011-05-01 00:00:00,1762,City1,Domain1
>
> 2011-06-01 00:00:00,1932,City1,Domain1

Error Message:

> Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(index(dfplot)) : 'origin' must be supplied

R Code (for errorred code, go to comment **#Nicely Plot the Data**):

```
  # Plot

  ######################################

  #Merge Time Series and Export Data
dfplot <- merge(as.xts(InputDataTimeSeries), as.xts(pred$lower))
dfplot <- merge(dfplot, as.xts(pred$mean))
dfplot <- merge(dfplot, as.xts(pred$upper))
dfplot <- merge(dfplot, as.xts(pred$fitted))

names(dfplot)[1:7] <- c("actuals", "lower80", "lower95", "predicted", "upper80", "upper95", "fitted")

#Nicely Plot the Data
ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=as.POSIXct(index(dfplot)))) +
geom_line(aes(y=fitted), col='grey90', size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(y=predicted), col='orange', size= 1) +
geom_line(aes(y=actuals), col='orange', size= 1) +

geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower80,ymax=upper80),alpha=0.3, fill="orange") +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower95,ymax=upper95),alpha=0.1, fill="orange") +
theme_bw() +
geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct(end(InputDataTimeSeries))), linetype="dashed", fill="gray40") +
labs(title=paste(pred$method, "80/95% PI Bands" ) , x="Time", y="Observed / Fitted") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
```

Comment: Without seeing a sample of the data is very difficult to provide a meaningful answer.  For starters: Where does the `index` function come from?  Does `index(dfplot)` return a number or a character string?

Comment: **Inputdata** is the original data. R global environment says the dataframe of **Inputdata** has 4 fields. The 1st field is **YEARMONTH: chr "2011-04-01 00:00:00"**. So the index originally was a character string. **Inputdata** then becomes **InputDataTimeSeries**. From the code, **InputDataTimeSeries** is what make **dfplot**. But the strange thing is I cannot see **InputDataTimeSeries** in the global environment. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't believe this is a right application to use the `index` function.  Just try using `ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=as.POSIXct(YEARMONTH)))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Error is now: _Error in as.POSIXct(YEARMONTH) : object 'YEARMONTH' not found_

Comment: I just try to add the origin, and it worked. `ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=as.POSIXct(index(dfplot),origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC")))`. Any ideas why?